# Teradata Character Column with non alphabet values

Tags: sql, teradata

I have a name column in Teradata that has customer full name all in one column. There are some names with -,_,.,/,#,! in between the name characters. I want to be able to pull records where there are names with these conditions. Is there a better option to pull records with the scenario below?

Currently, I am writing query like this
SELECT NAME FROM TABLESOURCE WHERE NAME LIKE ANY('%-%','%.%','%#%','%~%','%!%')

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use a regex, this filters for any characters outside of the a-z range: `where regexp_similar(name, '.*[^a-z]+.*', 'i') = 1`

Comment: Thanks for your response dnoeth, I got an error 9234 saying the pattern is not a valid pattern. By the way, I need to be able to pull records with any of the above characters. For example lets say a name has the following values Sarah% Trista Norman, Mike $Silver, Travis! Styles, Jamie Fong, Joe Doe. I should get results such as Sarah% Trista Norman, Mike $Silver, Travis! Styles using query LIKE NAME ANY('%$%','%!%').  I created a test data and could not extract a row with % in the names. I wrote LIKE NAME'%%%'. How to get rows of names that has % in it?

Comment: `'.*[^a-z]+.*'` is a valid pattern, what's your Teradata release? You might also list those known characters: `where regexp_similar(name, '..*[-%_.\/#!$]+.*', 'i') = 1`.  Regarding `%` in LIKE you must escape it `like '%\%%' escape '\'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested this but I think you could test for equality when those characters are removed from the name using `otranslate`

```
select name 
from tablesource 
where name <> otranslate(name,'-.#~!','')
```

Comment: HI Phil, Thanks so much for prompt response. I did use your suggestion and the query worked like a charm.